# Autofill single text box in datasheet instead of entire column

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a main form for projects that I work. Each project can have a single contact or 20 contacts. I would like to have a subform in datasheet view that I can have a combobox linked to my contacts query and autofills the next few columns with email and phone numbers automatically. I have one set up and put in macros on the after update event but it retrieves information fro the query but it changes the entire column not just the current record. I have tried to enter the macro in the current record event but that does not return any of the desired values (no values at all) Is there a vba or macro that will do this for me or am I putting my macro in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that an unbound control - your combobox - will show the same value for all records.

For individual values to be shown, the control must be bound to a field of the recordset of the form.

Comment: The combobox is bound to Company Name and each record will allow for a different combbox entry. That column will not change but the text in the following columns will only show the last entered combobox change - see example:

Comment: Combobox / Email
Company A/ EmployeeC@company.com
Store B/         EmployeeC@company.com
Employee C/ EmployeeC@company.com